# Merge csv to shp: return with DataFrame instead of GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, merge, shapefile

I would like to join the table to shp and plot the Map out using Python. However, the merged DataFrame is no longer a GeoDataFrame... why??? Anyone can help please~~~

```py
# Important library for many geopython libraries
!apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal 
# Install rtree - Geopandas requirment
!apt install python3-rtree 
# Install Geopandas
!pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
# Install descartes - Geopandas requirment
!pip install descartes 
# Install Folium for Geographic data visualization
!pip install folium
# Install plotlyExpress
!pip install plotly_express

# Import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import folium
import plotly_express as px


file1 = 'GEO.shp'
GEO = gpd.read_file(file1)

file2 = 'data.csv'
DATA = gpd.read_file(file2)

Join = GEO.merge(DATA, left_on='Code', right_on='M_code')

type(Join)

## Return --> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: you can't joint your csv file to a GeoDataFrame unless it has a `geometry` column.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick, use pandas to read-in the csv, not geopandas, otherwise you will get a geometry column full of nulls.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

file1 = 'GEO.shp'
GEO = gpd.read_file(file1)

file2 = 'data.csv'
DATA = pd.read_csv(file2) # <-- this should use pandas!!!

Join = GEO.merge(DATA, left_on="Code", right_on="M_code")
type(Join)
geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame
# OR
Join = pd.merge(GEO, DATA, left_on="Code", right_on="M_code")
```

take a look at the [docs](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#attribute-joins)